# python - why is the value of y in the input different from the output?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, numerical-methods

why is the value of y in the input different from the output?

in the input I put 14.6 210 then the output produces 1.46210 this makes my newton interpolation calculation not correct

```
import numpy as np

x = [0,8,16,24]
y = [14.6210,11.8430,9.8700,8.4180]

xinput = 12

n = len(x)-1

ST = np.zeros((n+1,n+1))

ST[:,0] = y

for k in range (1,n+1):
  for i in range (0,n-k+1):
    ST[i,k] = (ST[i+1,k-1] - ST[i,k-1]) / (x[i+k] - x[i])



print(ST)
p = ST[0,0]
for i in range(1, n+1):
  a = ST[0,i]

  for k in range (0,i):
    a = a * (xinput - x[k])
  p = p + a

print(p)
```

Comment: add you code and simple input and output

Comment: Edit the question to show your code properly formatted, don't put it into a comment.

Comment: hasn't it just turned them to scientific notation? ```1.46210000e+01 ``` is ```14.6210```?

Comment: @Nin17 no, i have done the calculation manually but the result is different

Comment: where is the output 1.46210? at ```print(ST)```?

Comment: @Nin17 yes, at print(ST)

Comment: Then what I said above is correct? It is showing 1.46210000e+01 which is 14.6210 which is the input?

Comment: @Nin17so the conclusion is 1.46210000e+01 = 14.6210 ?, then why is the calculation manually different from the code method

Comment: Well I'd have to know what you are doing manually to be able to answer that

Comment: @Nin17 for example, I want to find the value of f[x1,x0], I use the formula f(x1)-f(x0)/x1-x0, knowing the value x0 = 0; x1 = 8; f(x0) = 14,6210; f(x1) = 11.8430, I calculated with the above formula manually the result is -0.3472 different like in python, it produces the value -3.47250000e-01

Comment: -0.3472 is the same as -3.47250000e-01

Comment: @Nin17 please tell me how to calculate it or is there a youtube channel for me to study?

Comment: I can't find a good link to explain it but it is giving the result in scientific notation. If the format is 123456e2 that means 123456 * 10 ** 2

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations

Comment: @Nin17 one more question, how do I change the number in print(ST) so that it doesn't look like 1.46210000e+01 , I want to output only 4 values ​​after the comma, I've used round() but it always gets an error

Comment: you can change ```print(ST)``` to ```print([['{:.4f}'.format(i) for i in j] for j in ST])``` but this will print them as strings ( with ' around the number) or you can do this ```print([[float('{:.4f}'.format(i)) for i in j] for j in ST])``` but this won't have them all to 4 decimal places but to a maximum of 4 decimal places

Comment: Note that in python 3 you can do the formatting `'{:.4f}'.format(x)` more compactly as `f'{x:.4f}'`. Instead of formatting back and forth, possibly generating new floating-point errors, you can also assemble the strings directly as `'\n'.join(', '.join(f'{x:6.4f} for x in row) for row in ST)`.